# Is it possible to compile a .NET 2 WinForms application to run on .NET 4, if no .NET 2 is installed?

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, runtime, fusion

Recently I got a customer complaint, that a small .NET 2.0 application I wrote did not run on his Windows 7 computer.

After investigating, I found out that there was no folder `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` on his machine, just the folder for V4.0.

I was unaware that such a constellation is even possible.

**My question:**

Is it somehow possible to instruct my application to use the .NET 4 runtime, if no .NET 2 runtime is found on a client machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`<supportedRuntime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) element in app.config.

So for example, you can write an app.config file of:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jon. Would it be possible to place the information right inside the application executable or is the `App.config` file the only way?

Comment: @Uwe: I don't believe you can put it *in* the executable, no. But the good news is you don't need to ship your customer a new executable - just a tiny config file. (Which will of course be MyApplication.config or whatever the application name is, rather than app.config.)